# Use variable $USER_HOME in New-Item -ItemType Directory

Tags: windows, powershell, environment-variables

What specific syntax must be changed in the command below in order to have PowerShell create the `mysubdirectory` in the `$USER_HOME` directory regardless of what that directory is named on any given machine?

The command we are currently using in GitHub runners is brittle because it explicitly types the GitHub runner's user home as follows:

```
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path C:\\Users\\runneradmin\\mysubdirectory\\
```

How to modify the above one-line command to express `$USER_HOME` as a variable instead of as the brittle string `C:\\Users\\runneradmin`?

Comment: Are you perhaps after `$env:USERPROFILE`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerShell's [automatic `$HOME` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#home) reflects the current user's home (profile) directory, which on Windows is equivalent to `$env:USERPROFILE` (the `USERPROFILE` environment variable)<sup>[1]</sup> - in spite of what the linked help topic states, as of this writing;<sup>[2]</sup> on Unix-like platforms, it is the equivalent of `$env:HOME`:

```bash
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $HOME\mysubdirectory
```

As an aside: `\` is *not* a metacharacter in PowerShell, so there's no reason to double it for literal use.

---

<sup>[1] Arguably, it should be the equivalent of `${env:HOMEDRIVE}${env:HOMEPATH}` instead, which is *by default and typically* the same as `$env:USERPROFILE`, but can be configured to point to a different location - see [this comment on GitHub issue #17685](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/17685#issuecomment-1186317371) for background information.</sup>

<sup>[2] [GitHub docs issue #9463](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/9463) requests a correction.</sup>